# Filtering a module by square zero extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, deformation-theory

**It is claimed:** Let $A^\eta \rightarrow A$ be a square zero extension of commutative ring. i.e. kernel $I^2=0$. Let $X$ be $A^\eta$-module. Then we can obtain a filtration
$$ 0 \rightarrow X' \rightarrow X \rightarrow X'' \rightarrow 0$$

of $A^\eta$ modules such that $I$ acts trivially on $X', X''$.

---

Some comments would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, $A$ does not actually play any role in your question?  You are just asking about a ring $A^\eta$ with an ideal $I$ satisfying $I^2=0$?

Comment: I also don't know what map $A^\eta\to X$ you're talking about.

Comment: Yea I believe so: in this case: $A=A^\eta/I$. Yes, oh wait I was thinking $X$ as an $A^\eta$ algebra. Now my attempt above is absurdly wrong. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let $X'=IX$ and $X''=X/IX$.  Then $IX''=0$ trivially, and $IX'=I^2X=0$ since $I^2=0$.